# Why is Ruby Bignum not working?

Tags: ruby

Here is what I have:
[image: Terminal screenshot]

Using temporary variables, I have:

[image]

Why do `10 ** 18` and `10 ** 20` work fine, but `10 ** 19` doesn't?

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in Ruby 1.8.7. It has been fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/4e4649e13cd4175aab75a0edc2fc5b082cf735d1).
Just upgrade to the latest version and everything will work fine.

Here are some tests on 1.9.3:

[image]

Here is the text representation ([for blind users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252165/why-is-ruby-bignum-not-working#comment23255241_16252199)):

```
1.9.3p362 :001 > 10 ** 18
 => 1000000000000000000 
1.9.3p362 :002 > 10 ** 19
 => 10000000000000000000 
1.9.3p362 :003 > 10 ** 20
 => 100000000000000000000 
1.9.3p362 :004 > 10 ** 21
 => 1000000000000000000000 
1.9.3p362 :005 > 10 ** 22
 => 10000000000000000000000 
1.9.3p362 :006 > 10 ** 23
 => 100000000000000000000000
```

Here's the list of commands I've run:

```
irb
10 ** 18
10 ** 19
10 ** 20
10 ** 21
10 ** 22
10 ** 23
```

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, The image was important to show the version of Ruby `irb` and to *prove* it correctly works. It's not like a bunch of numbers are important to be searchable or accessible in this very context.

Comment: No, it’s not, you can just as well include the version in a text representation—in fact, copy-and-pasting your terminal’s contents would do *exactly* that. What if I want to run these commands for myself? What if I was a blind user? Search-ability is only one of many reasons, and there’s *no* reason it needs to be an image.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, you are absolutely right.